# Woocommerce send email on order

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, orders

I need anything that, when a order is created, it sends in addition to the email that goes to the costumer, an email to one of my email accouts with only some information the customer inserted, such as:

- Name
- Surname
- Street
- Country etc.

How could I archive this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=email&section=wc_email_new_order` or from the dashboard:

- Go to the WooCommerce sections and in that go to the Settings
- In settings click on the Email tab and in that click on the New Order tab.

At the bottom of that page there is a button called: "Copy file to theme", click on that and then click on the "View Template" button. Replace the contents of the email from `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading ); ?>` down with:

```
<h2><?php _e( 'Customer details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

<?php echo $order->get_formatted_billing_address(); ?>

<?php if ( $order->billing_email ) : ?>
<p><strong><?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_email; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ( $order->billing_phone ) : ?>
<p><strong><?php _e( 'Tel:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->billing_phone; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The above removes the order details and keeps the customers details.